# AngularJS Bootstrap progressbar max changing

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

When the value of "max" in a progressbar is changed the progressbar will not update its relative progress.

```
<progressbar max="max" value="dynamic"><span style="color:black; white-space:nowrap;">{{dynamic}} / {{max}}</span></progressbar>
```

By using a method to randomise the max value

```
$scope.random = function() {
var other = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 100);
var type;

if (value < 25) {
  type = 'success';
} else if (value < 50) {
  type = 'info';
} else if (value < 75) {
  type = 'warning';
} else {
  type = 'danger';
}

$scope.showWarning = (type === 'danger' || type === 'warning');
$scope.max = other;
$scope.type = type;  };
```

I have an ugly work around but I would like to know if there is a neater way

```
<progressbar value="dynamic/max*100"><span style="color:black; white-space:nowrap;">{{dynamic}} / {{max}}</span></progressbar>
```

See Example here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/urZH8i2sJUeeTgIJ7JWU?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to decorate the `progressbar` and `bar` directive via **[`$provide.decorate()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide)** during the configuration phase. Inside the decorator, you need to add an observer via **[`attr.$observe()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes)** to observe an attribute, **`dynamicMax`**, with its interpolated value. The callback for the observer must update the following isolated variables:

[**1**] **scope.max**

***REFERENCES:***

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/progressbar/progressbar.js#L13

[**2**] **scope.percent**

***REFERENCES:***

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/progressbar/progressbar.js#L23
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/progressbar/progressbar.js#L61
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/progressbar/progressbar.js#L78
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/progressbar/progressbar.html

---

**[PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/7utfQQ9klROS7CtTUoyT?p=preview)**

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  .config(function($provide) {

    var progressDecorator = function($delegate) {
      var directive = $delegate[0];
      var compile = directive.compile;
      var link = directive.link;

      directive.compile = function() {
        compile.apply(this, arguments);

        return function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
          link.apply(this, arguments);

          if(angular.isDefined(attr.dynamicMax)) {
            attr.$observe('dynamicMax', function(max) {
              scope.max = max;
              scope.percent = +(100 * scope.value / max).toFixed(2);
            });  
          }

        };
      };

      return $delegate;
    };

    $provide.decorator('progressbarDirective', progressDecorator);
    $provide.decorator('barDirective', progressDecorator);
  });
```

**HTML**

*Usage*

```
<progressbar dynamic-max="{{max}}" value="value">
  <span style="color:black; white-space:nowrap;">{{value}} / {{max}}</span>
</progressbar>
```

Notice that there is a new attribute called `dynamic-max`. This is the attribute that is being observe in to change the maximum value, use this instead of `max` if you want to have a dynamic maximum value. Take note that you need to assign an interpolated value(the value has to be wrapped in a `{{}}`.

**[DECORATING DIRECTIVES REFERENCE](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/)**

Comment: Thanks, that seems like the most effective solution to keep the keep the progress bar clean especially in a situation where I will be using dynamic-max more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `example.js`, the reason why the progress bar will not update itself is because your `$scope.dynamic = value;` is comment out. Uncomment it, your progress bar seems to work fine. Also, keep in mind that `max` is the **total** value of the progress (default to 100), so I am unsure why you would want it to be changing dynamically; `value` is the one that's supposed to change.

Take a look at the `example.js` of this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YliArJYCFZQNA2T2LUun?p=preview).

EDIT: Fix plnkr link as per OP's comment.

Comment: The issue is that I am using them as "health bars" for the actual implementation and so if the max health increases the bars start to do some of the weird things I spoke about.

Also, you made a mistake linking the plnkr.